# Android SwipeRefreshLayout refresh indicator not visible

Tags: java, android, xml, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using the android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout inside of a fragment. The swipe works perfectly to refresh my data but all I can see is a blank white circle as a swipe indicator. All of the other questions I have seen about this do not seem to work.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_assets,container,false);
    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mSwipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    mSwipeLayout.setColorSchemeColors(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    return view;
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Dependencies

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.1.0'
```

How can I get this refresh indicator to work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that `setColorSchemeColors()` expects color integers as inputs (e.g. `Color.BLUE`), not color resource IDs.

You should use [`setColorSchemeResources()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setColorSchemeResources(int...)) instead, which accepts color resource references.

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you so much. (Will accept as answer as soon as it lets me.)